# Twitter api keeps loading the same 2 tweets. Doesn't update

Tags: php, twitter

At the moment I am working on a website where the front page requires a twitter api to get the latest 5 tweets. I use `twitterAPIexchange.php` from Github to get the twitter data.

What happens is that it just keeps loading the same 2 posts from 10 days ago. I created a couple new posts, but the api doesn't respond and keeps loading the same 2 posts from 10 days ago even though i have deleted them already.

I hope i have given the right information. If you need me to give more information i would happy to help ofcourse. Who can help me?

This is my **code:**

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');


    /** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "Token",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "secret",
    'consumer_key' => "key",
    'consumer_secret' => "secret"
);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
$getfield = '?screen_name=username&count=5';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);



$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE); 



if (isset($string["errors"][0]["message"]) != "") {
    echo        
    "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";    
    exit();} ?>


    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 border-top" >



            <?php   
            foreach($string as $item)



                $user = $item->user; 
                $user_name = $item->user->name;             
                $user_screen_name = $item->user->screen_name;
                $user_profile_image_url = $item->user->profile_image_url;
                $user_text = $item->text;


                { ?>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <div class="twitter-news">
                        <img  src="<?php echo $user_profile_image_url;?> alt="<?php $user_name;?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10" >
                    <div class="twitter-feed" style=" clear: both;">
                        <h2 style="font-weight:bold; font-size:15px;"><?php echo $user_name ;?></h2>
                        <p style ="font-size:14px;"><?php  echo $user_text; ?></p>              
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>  

        <?php    }

} ?>
```